# How do I add package in the logcat logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat

I am using adb logcat in cmd Windows and I want to filter only logs from a specific app.

Using the command adb logcat | findstr package doesn't work because the logs format doesn't contain package, so only logs that contain the package in their tag/description are showed. I know I can select a certain format using adb logcat -v raw/threadtime/etc. but it seems no option contains package. It's strange that in Android Studio the package is visible.

Logs in Android Studio logcat:

[image]